# How to install gnome-open in ubuntu 20.04 desktop

Tags: 20.04, gnome-open

In ubuntu 18.04 desktop, I used to install `gnome-open` via:

```
sudo apt install libgnome2-bin
```

So that I could open a folder from terminal via command line, e.g:

```
gnome-open /mnt/star/note
```

But, seems in ubuntu 20.04, `libgnome2-bin` is not available, so how can I install `gnome-open`, or how can I open a folder from terminal via command line?

Answer (score 9):

Another solution found is:

```
xdg-open /mnt/star/note
```

Seems `xdg-open` is available on ubuntu 20.04, by default.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use:

```
gio open /mnt/star/note
```

Comment: This is good, but I have just found another solution: `xdg-open /mnt/star/note`, both works.